# LaTeX: Float too large warning

Tags: tables, floats, warnings

I have a table like shown below but when I compile it I'm getting a warning like this

> LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 18.73247pt on input line 1125.

I have searched related problems I couldn't find though

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Default value: 6pt \begin{table}[!ht]

 %\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.95}

\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}}   
 \hline                 

 \texttt{Objects Name}&\texttt{Vsys(I)}&\texttt{Vsys(II)}&\texttt{OffsetI} &\texttt{OffsetII}&\texttt{VmaxI}&\texttt{VmaxII}&\texttt{Vesc} \\
  \texttt{}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}\\
  \texttt{(1)}&\texttt{(2)}&\texttt{(3)}&\texttt{(4)}&\texttt{(5)}&\texttt{(6)}&\texttt{(7)}&\texttt{(8)}\\
    \hline \hline   
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\        



  \hline                                                                                                  
 \end{tabular}                                                                                              
 \caption*{Notes-col(1):Name of target,col(2 and 3):the systemic velocity V\textsubscript{sys} of the galaxy for the two methods,method I and method 2 ,col(4 and 5):Offset velocities $\Delta$V and ,col(6 and 7): maximum velocities,col(8):escape velocity.Note:I and II indicates  the two methods  where V\textsubscript{sys} estimated from the continuum and from the rotation curve respectively.}   
 \label{calculated}                                                                                     
 \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide a complete example we can compile. Too big for a page how large? We don't know. However, the problem is that the contents of the `table` environment are simply too big for the page. You have various options: use bigger paper and/or a greater proportion of the paper; make the content smaller; claim that you are making an artistic statement and that the missing material is essential to your right to free expression. The plausibility of the last, like paper size, is geographically variable.

Comment: It isn't the caption that is too large, particularly, is it? Certainly the warning doesn't say that. Obviously, your code doesn't compile, so I can't test without completing it first. Why do you think it is the caption specifically?

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
... \end{document}`, your MWE only gives an `Overfull \hbox` which can be easily avoided putting `Name` on the second row. I can't reproduce your warning, please add a complete 
[minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Hi crf,thanks for the response. when I compile it,its giving me a warning like LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 18.73247pt on input line 1163.I said it might be too large caption coz the warning is highlighting that part of the table. I cant add the fool packages I used coz its too big

Answer (score 4):

The warning

> LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 18.73247pt on input line
>   1125.

simply means, that a float (in your case the table) is to long to fit completly on one page.  The code you gave does not result in this error, but please see the following MWE (I added package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins and I added more table rows to get a table going over the page):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Default value: 6pt \begin{table}[!ht]
 %\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.95}
\caption*{Notes-col(1): Name of target, col(2 and 3): the systemic velocity V\textsubscript{sys} of the galaxy for the two methods, method I and method 2, col(4 and 5): Offset velocities $\Delta$V and, col(6 and 7): maximum velocities, col(8): escape velocity. Note: I and II indicates the two methods where V\textsubscript{sys} estimated from the continuum and from the rotation curve respectively.}   
\label{calculated}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}l@{\hspace{2mm}}}   
 \hline                 

 \texttt{Objects}&\texttt{Vsys(I)}&\texttt{Vsys(II)}&\texttt{OffsetI} &\texttt{OffsetII}&\texttt{VmaxI}&\texttt{VmaxII}&\texttt{Vesc} \\
  \texttt{Name}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}&\texttt{(km/s)}\\
  \texttt{(1)}&\texttt{(2)}&\texttt{(3)}&\texttt{(4)}&\texttt{(5)}&\texttt{(6)}&\texttt{(7)}&\texttt{(8)}\\
    \hline \hline   
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\        
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
 text        &14431.78&        & 17.35   &       & 178.6   &       &459      \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Now we get a warning

> LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 12.44225pt on input line
>   61.

and can see the problem in the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

You see that there is one row reaching outside the typing area.  Therefore you have to shorten the data for one row or the caption or break the table into two parts or simpy use environment `longtable` instead `table` and `tabular` ...

Which solution would you prefer?